# web2py adding themeforest theme

Tags: web2py

How to add custom theme in web2py. Example: in themeforest.net, one of the theme have folder structure as follows:

[image: Sample themeforest.net theme stucture]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upload the themeforest CSS, javascript and image  files to the `Static` folder in web2py.

Create the html files in `Views` then link to those CSS, javascript and image files from the html you created in the `Views`.

In your html file in the `Views` you should delete this:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<h1>This is the default/sample.html template</h1>
{{=BEAUTIFY(response._vars)}}
```

and copy your html code from your themeforest html files since you are not using the web2py default layout.html

This is how you can link to the `css` file (or the js files) you have uploaded to the `Static` folder from your web2py `Views` html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{{=URL('static', 'css/style.css')}}">
```